# Interpreting history in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

In my Production branch I have a merge that occured on 6/3/2011.  The merge comes from QA, but for some reason one of the files **Global.asax** did not merge. The Global.asax file is not even part of the list of updated files. Is there any way to tell why?

For example, if the developer used the merge tool and told it to take the target version instead of the source version.  Can I see that they chose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens all the time at our company.  We have a branching strat that we merge up from dev branches to main.

Things that can happen:

- TFS does not recognize a change the
  file and ignores during merge
- User decides not to merge and ignores
  local changes
- User decides to merge and merges
  existing with local
- User disregards local changes and
  takes server version

*where local = branch to merge*

To answer you question "Can I see that they chose this" no, to the best of my knowledge, there is not way to do this because it is simply updating the file or not updating the file.  The conflict and merge tools are just there to assist you in file merge modifications not so much for historical tracking of how you merged.